# How to Run Python Code on Replit's Deployement

Tags: python, automation, replit

anyone here with experience of running python code at replit? they had an always on option in past which is now replaced by deployement, i have a simple python code that needs to run daily at 9am to update an google sheet, can anyone help explaining how i can run it there just like always on, thank you